# Cannot get current spinner position with setOnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, position, android-spinner

I am trying to retrieve the spinner's **selected position**. The values inside the spinner are of type **String** and I am using **setOnItemSelectedListener** to change a class String variable to the one that has been selected and use it later on:

```
spinner = (MaterialBetterSpinner) myToolbar.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,socialMediaOptions);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           socialMedia =  parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

private void sendPost(){
    Log.v(TAG, socialMedia);
}
```

The problem is that the variable does not change when an item is selected, it seems like **onItemSelected** is not being called when there is a change in the spinner selection

Comment: http://www.android-examples.com/get-selected-item-position-of-spinner-in-android/ check this

Comment: you can get item from array list instead `socialMedia =socialMediaOptions.get(position)`

Comment: in OnItemSelected `spinner.setSelection(selectedPosition)` hope this will help you.

Comment: @RavishSharma **getSelectedItemPosition** is not one of the spinner methods, the spinner is  of type **MaterialBetterSpinner**

Comment: @Redman tried it, it should have worked, from what I am understanding is that the onItemSelected is not being called.

Comment: display a Toast inside `onItemSelected`  and see if toast is getting displayed

Comment: checkout my edit..........

Comment: Fixed it !, @Hetfieldan24 pointed out that BetterSpinner uses EditText instead of Spinner, Thank you very much for your input Redman and siva35

Answer (score 0):

Hope your  socialMediaOptions are string array like this

```
socialMediaOptions={"FB","TWIT","IN"}
```

then

// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears

**add this line**

> `adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);`

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

  socialMedia = socialMediaOptions[position];

  }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

  }
  });
```

Comment: Tried that, this should work but it seems like **onItemSelected** is not being called

Answer (score 0):

See this thread:
https://github.com/Lesilva/BetterSpinner/issues/42
There said that BetterSpinner extends EditText, that's why onItemSelectedListener is not being called. You should use TextChangedListener instead.

Comment: Glad to help you :)